# What is the return value of va_arg in empty lists?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

In case of using variable arguments in cpp, what does va_arg return as the next value in case there is no next value?

Also, can this be considered as a solution for counting the elements in va_list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Undefined Behavior to do this, so you can't say anything about it. It's certainly unsuitable for counting.

Use variadic templates instead, those allow you to count arguments.

Comment: can you please explain why the developers did not take the pain of returning some value in this case? i don't think it is so difficult.